# grep alias to safely ignore multiple directories

Tags: grep, alias

The day to day usage is:

```
grep -rIn pattern directory
```

There are some files that I want to avoid, they are in directories that have this kind of path in them at some point: `app/lib/bower/lodash`, `app/lib/bower/paho-mqtt-js`, `app/lib/bower/socket-io-client`.

Ideal solution is to detect `app/lib/bower/` in the path, but it's hard. Is it possible?

I've come up with:

```
alias grep='grep --exclude-dir={lodash,paho-mqtt-js,socket-io-client}'
```

Good enough (though needs maintenance when new stuff is added). How to at least add a short warning into stderr if the directory is excluded by grep?

Comment: Why not just use `alias exgrep='grep --exclude-dir={lodash,paho-mqtt-js,socket-io-client}'`, so if you use exgrep, you know there is something excluded?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `find`:

```
mygrep() (
  pattern=$1; shift
  find "$@" -type d -path '*/app/lib/bower' -exec sh -c '
    printf >&2 "Warning: ignoring \"%s\" directory\n" "$@"
    ' sh {} + -prune -o -type f -exec grep -IHne "$pattern" {} +
)
```

(`-I` and `-H` being GNU extensions).

Use as:

```
mygrep pattern dir1 dir2
```

(making sure `dir1` and `dir2` don't look like `find` predicates).

Remove the `-exec sh...+` if you don't care about those warning messages.

It's a bad idea to use `grep` as your alias name when you change its behaviour so dramatically.

If you need to pass options to `grep`, you could use the `GREP_OPTIONS` variable like:

```
GREP_OPTIONS=-i mygrep foo dir
```

But note that support for that option will be removed in future versions of `grep`, so a better option might be to give a way in `mygrep` to pass options to `grep` like with a dedicated array if your shell supports them:

```
mygrep() (
  pattern=$1; shift
  find "$@" -type d -path '*/app/lib/bower' -exec sh -c '
    printf >&2 "Warning: ignoring \"%s\" directory\n" "$@"
    ' sh {} + -prune -o -type f -exec \
    grep -IHne "${g[@]}" "$pattern" {} +
)

g=(-i --exclude-dir=.git); mygrep foo dir1 dir2
```

Or use `--` to tell `mygrep` where the options stop:

```
mygrep() (
  grep_options=()
  for i do
    grep_options+=("$i")
    shift
    [ "$i" != "--" ] || break
  done
  pattern=${1?need a pattern}; shift
  find "$@" -type d -path '*/app/lib/bower' -exec sh -c '
    printf >&2 "Warning: ignoring \"%s\" directory\n" "$@"
    ' sh {} + -prune -o -type f -exec \
    grep -H "${grep_options[@]}" "$pattern" {} +
)

mygrep -nI --exclude-dir=.git -- pattern dir1 dir2
```

(and make sure you don't pass `--` as an option arguments, as in if you want to exclude the `--` files, use `--exclude=--`, not `--exclude --` for instance. That also precludes usages like `mygrep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 -- dir` or `mygrep -f patternfile -- dir`).

Comment: That's a different syntax.

Comment: @Velkan if you mean that `g=(-i --exclude-dir=.git); mygrep foo dir1 dir2` is a different syntax from `grep -i --exclude-dir=.git -rIn foo dir1 dir2`, then yes but for `mygrep` to be able to understand that syntax, we'd need  it to know which of those arguments are the pattern and the directories and for that we'd need it to implement the full option parser of your `grep`  implementation which would not be practical.